# Windows software deployment and patching tools

Tags: deployment

I'd like to know your thoughts on a solid commercial, or open source, software deployment and patching tool. We've been down the route of WPKG (good, but quite a lot of work and no reporting of roll-out progress), GFI Languard - doesn't handle custom package deployment very well and the 3rd party patch detection was poor (we have custom in-house software to deploy occasionally).

Any ideas are welcome as we're wasting huge amounts of time on login scripts/writing custom XML scripts to deploy software, that's without starting the 3rd party patching.

Answer (score 3):

If you are a Microsoft shop, [SCCM](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/configuration-manager/cm-overview.aspx) would be a good fit.

Answer (score 2):

For commercial products I'd do a comparison between Microsoft's SCCM, IBM's Tivoli Endpoint Manager, and maybe Symantec's Altiris products.

I've only got experice in Tivoli Endpoint Manager (TEM, formerly known as BigFix). It does software deployment + OS patching + 3rd party app patching, with pre-made tools for software deployment and patching, and also good methods for running custom tasks. It can target Windows, *nixes and OS X.

There's an active community at http://forum.bigfix.com/, you could send a question with more details on your needs there and see if it fits.

Answer (score 1):

In a Windows environment you can use [WSUS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb332157) for operating system updates.

Also take a look at the [Admin Arsenal](http://www.adminarsenal.com/) website. They have some interesting products.

Answer (score 0):

If the main concern is roll-out progress, then [wpkgCreateReport](http://www.gig-mbh.de/edv/software/wpkgtools/wpkg-create-report-english.htm) and "[Ugly perl script to check if packages are installed on a set of workstations](http://lists.wpkg.org/pipermail/wpkg-users/attachments/20080327/eafdecb8/attachment.bin)" (rename that attachment.bin link to something.pl -- it's a perl script) may be of use. Both of these are linked at [WPKG's contributed software page](http://wpkg.org/User_contributed_software).

Note that for either of these, you'll need to ensure that your wpkg.xml files get copied up to a central location after the runs finish. Either do this with an "Execute after" in WPKG client, or automatically point it to the server according to [these instructions](http://wpkg.org/Viewing_software_installed_on_workstations).

I'm elbow-deep in testing WPKG at the moment. 50-60 packages down, two major ones (and roughly a dozen minor ones) to go.